# Can I run the file on a specific path, e.g. C: \ users \% username% \ desktop \ Cs.exe from .bat when it is on a pendrive?

Tags: batch-file, usb-drive

Start "" "C: \ users \% username% \ desktop \ Cs.exe"
It doesn't work.

Comment: Well, if you actually put those spaces in your code, it's because there are no spaces in your actual path, so you're telling the computer to run a program that doesn't exist.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that if `%username%` is not your own profile, it is unlikely that you'll have permission to run it without specifically gaining that permission first.

Comment: Are you saying cs.exe is on a pendrive?  You could copy it to the desktop.  You could change the current working directory to the desktop and then run cs.exe from the pendrive.  Just too may questions here.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above your problem is that you have spaces in your file path.
Plus, running the batch file will only execute the exe at the path of the current logged-in user.

```
Start "" "C:\users\%username%\desktop\Cs.exe"
```

This code will launch the Cs.exe file on your desktop.